# Parallel.ForEach - Access To Modified Closure Applies?

Tags: c#, .net, closures, parallel.foreach

I've read a number of other questions about Access to Modified closure so I understand the basic principle. Still, I couldn't tell - does `Parallel.ForEach` have the same issues?

Take the following snippet where I recompute the usage stats for users for the last week as an example:

```
var startTime = DateTime.Now;
var endTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(6);
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    // this next line gives me "Access To Modified Closure"
    Parallel.ForEach(allUsers, user => UpdateUsageStats(user, startTime, endTime));

    // move back a day and continue the process
    startTime = startTime.AddDays(-1);
    endTime = endTime.AddDays(-1);
}
```

From what I know of this code the `foreach` should run my `UpdateUsageStats` routine right away and start/end time variables won't be updated till the next time around the loop. Is that correct or should I use local variables to make sure there aren't issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **are** accessing a modified closure, so it does apply. **But**, you are not changing its value while you are using it, so assuming you are not changing the values inside `UpdateUsageStats` you don't have a problem here.

`Parallel.Foreach` waits for the execution to end, and only then are you changing the values in `startTime` and `endTime`.

Comment: So is there *ever* a situation where `Parallel.Foreach` would have a closure issue or is the warning just because I'm using a lambda?

Comment: @drew_w There is indeed. If you would have been changing its value while inside the Prallel.Foreach

Comment: But the only way to do that in would be with a `ref` variable passed into the calling routine or task. Correct?

Comment: @drew_w no, you could do that right inside the anonymous method like user => { Console.Writeline(endTime); endTime = DateTime.Now;}

Answer (score 2):

"Access to modified closure" only leads to problems if the capture scope leaves the loop in which the capture takes place and is used elsewhere. For example,

```
var list = new List<Action>();
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
  list.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(i));
}
list.ForEach(a => a()); // prints "7" 7 times, because `i` was captured inside the loop
```

In your case the lamda doing the capture doesn't leave the loop (the `Parallel.ForEach` call is executed completely within the loop, each time around).

You still get the warning because the compiler doesn't know whether or not `Parallel.ForEach` is causing the the lambda to be stored for later invocation. Since we know more than the compiler we can safely ignore the warning.